# Set text-decoration underline on hover effect

Tags: html, css

I have a html

```
<div class="col store">
 <h4>POLICIES</h4>
  <ul>
     <li><a href="#">Shipping Policies</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Return Policy</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Terms of Use</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">How To Shop</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I want the a href to get underlined when hovered.

I have used this css, but still it isn't happening.

```
.col .about ul li a:hover
{
   text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Comment: Which element is `.about`? There is no such element in your markup.

Answer (score 5):

`.col` element doesn't have any `.about` descendants, so the selector simply fails! You should remove the `.about` part.

Answer (score 2):

Check following you updated code:

```css
.col ul li a:hover
{
   text-decoration: underline;
}

.col ul li a{
     text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="col store">
 <h4>POLICIES</h4>
  <ul>
     <li><a href="#">Shipping Policies</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Return Policy</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Terms of Use</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">How To Shop</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The css you pasted is not matching the markup in the page, so the solution to this is to rewrite your css by removing the missing markup element `.about`

```
.col ul li a:hover
{
   text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need to reference the class "col", then the "a" tag.

```css
.col a{
    color:red;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.col a:hover{
    text-decoration:underline;
    color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="col store">
 <h4>POLICIES</h4>
  <ul>
     <li><a href="#">Shipping Policies</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Return Policy</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Terms of Use</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">How To Shop</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ofsmnp8y/
Set your link preferences before hover, then set the preferences for hover, as shown in the example.

Please be aware you can also use :active, :link, :hover, :visited, and you will have to style these appropriately.